# Stanford dependency parser training data format

Tags: stanford-nlp, training-data, dependency-parsing

I would like to add a new language to the Stanford Dependency Parser, but cannot for the life of me figure out how.

In what format should training data be?
How do I generate new language files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The neural net dependency parser takes in CoNLL-X format data.

There is a description of the format in this paper:

https://ilk.uvt.nl/~emarsi/download/pubs/14964.pdf

Comment: Thanks, got it to work after some hacking around. Paper helped beautifully.